# Property '....' not found on object of type '.....' xcode 9.4 ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

These files working fine. I am facing issue only when google map integrate through `cocoapods`

```
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
```

This error occor in class of "ios-branch-deep-linking".

```
Property 'URLBlackList' not found on object of type 'BNCPreferenceHelper *'
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't used the libraries, but a quick read of the source and header on GitHub shows that `URLBlackList` appears in the .m but doesn't appear in the .h.  That implies that it is considered private by the authors.

see source: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/Branch-SDK/Branch-SDK/BNCPreferenceHelper.m   see header: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/corona-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/ios/Plugin/Branch-SDK/BNCPreferenceHelper.h

Answer (score 0):

After R&D finally i found solution https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking/issues/847.
I just update Branch on latest version and error has gone.